# Q: flutter new project failed

Tags: android, flutter

I installed flutter SDK and I have inserted its path in environment variables.and while I try to start a new flutter project in android studio, I get this issue: MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
How to solve this[lu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXEGa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try to start new project from the cmd - [test drive flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive?tab=terminal)

Comment: it has created a project but the issue is the same,here is the issue                                             18:40 Project Sync
   The project 'myappsrk' is not a Gradle-based project
   More Information about migrating to Gradle

18:40 Flutter device daemon
   Flutter device daemon #1: process exited during startup. Exit code: 1, stderr:
   'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.
   'MySQL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.